# WIX shortcut icon to exe adds exe twice

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to add icon to shortcut based on exe file in my wix 3.8 used in Visual Studio:

```
  <Component Id="my.exe" Guid="MY-GUID">
    <File Id="my.exe" Source="$(var.Project.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes">
      <Shortcut Id="MyShortcut" Directory="ApplicationMenuFolder" Name="My App" WorkingDirectory="ApplicationRootFolder" Icon="my.exe" IconIndex="0"  Advertise="yes">
        <Icon Id="my.exe"  SourceFile="$(var.Project.TargetPath)" />
      </Shortcut>
    </File>
  </Component>
```

The problem is that file `$(var.Project.TargetPath)` is added twice to MSI. I can prove it by removing icon reference. If I remove MSI is 3MB smaller than with Icon reference.

How can I setup shortcut icon to exe, which will use the same exe and do not add it twice to MSI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

im not 100% sure (couldn't find anything definitive in the installer reference) but i think advertised shortcuts can't use icons that are stored in a exe. the icon needs to be streamed into the icon table and is cached in the installer cache. if you want to save the 3mb you need to make it either non advertised or remove the icon from the exe and store it seperately in the icon table

Answer (score 4):

You are using the exe as the icon file:

```
<Icon Id="my.exe"  SourceFile="$(var.Project.TargetPath)" />
```

If you want to use a smaller file, such as an .ico file, change the Icon/@SourceFile to reference it. But, yes, you still need @Id to have the "same extension as the file that [the shortcut] points at" (.exe).

Comment: thanks for pointing out, that only th _Id_ has to have the extension!

Answer (score 2):

This is current WiX behavior.  I've filed a [feature request](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4340/) to improve this story.  Please feel free to leave a comment if you'd like the change.  Otherwise I suspect Rob will say functions as designed.

As a work around, extract your Icon from your EXE and use that in your Icon element instead.

Comment: Ok, I will add comment to that request.

Answer (score 0):

When you add that icon, you're just adding an icon that goes into the MSI file's Icon table. It's not really anything to do with that shortcut definition. So I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, although I can see why you get a bigger MSI file. Are you saying that the shortcut is missing, or has the wrong icon or something else?

Comment: I just want to avoid adding to msi the same file twice (in this case exe). It is how I understand smart cabbing - avoiding adding the same file twice to msi.

Comment: Smart cabbing only normalizes files being placed into cabs.  It doesn't look at other blog storage locations such as Binary table or Icon table.  Still, it does seem like a feature request/bug for WiX to extract the resource from the source path and only place the resource in the table not the entire EXE.  Still, the Windows Installer Icon table does say that Icon's can be in PE (EXE/DLL) format.

Comment: Thanks, for explanation, I'm new in WiX from Old VS Setup. And there it just worked... I've extracted icon and put it separately.